# Prolog predicates involving lists

Tags: prolog

I want to write a predicate that finds a particular element in a list, by comparing the lists. For example the data I could have for instance could be like:

```
likes(phil, [apple, banana, orange]).
likes(hetti, [apple, cherry, grapes]).
```

etc.

I just want someone to explain how something like this would work, because I've been trying to use member or select; but it seems to be more difficult to find information on this. Could I use pattern matching?

Comment: *finds a particular element in a list, by comparing the lists*... it's unclear what this means

Comment: Formulate the query you want to pose in plain English.

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that you want to know what the common likes are between `phil` and `hetti`. If so, then this is the code:

```
?- bothlike(phil, hetti, Ls), write(Ls), nl.

bothlike(X, Y, Ls) :-
    likes(X, Xs), 
    likes(Y, Ys), 
    intersection(Xs, Ys, Ls).

likes(phil, [apple, banana, orange]).
likes(hetti, [apple, cherry, grapes]).

intersection([], _, []).
intersection([H1|T1], L2, L3) :-
        member(H1, L2),
        !,
        L3 = [H1|T3],
        intersection(T1, L2, T3).
intersection([_|T1], L2, L3) :-
        intersection(T1, L2, L3).
```

It gives the answer `[apple]`.